# Application down "err_proxy_connection_failed"

Tags: windows, proxy

My application became suddenly down and I got this error in the browser :

**"err_proxy_connection_failed"**

A reboot fixed the issue but I don't understand what happened in the first place.

Do you know what does that error means ?

The server is an EC2 windows machine.